# Wordpress Admin: open popup window on a custom button

Tags: wp-admin

I am using custom meta box in wordpress post page. this box contains a custom Copy button. Now, I want to open a popup window on clicking 'copy' button. Also I need to show content of parent window in this popup.

Comment: The post edit screen has no parent window.

Comment: Please try to make this question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can open a thickbox with javascript.

A example with check for the height and width of the thickbox.

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!--
                        var viewportwidth,
                            viewportheight;
                        if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined' ) {
                            viewportwidth = window.innerWidth-80,
                            viewportheight = window.innerHeight-100
                        } else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
                            && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
                            'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
                        {
                            viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                            viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
                        } else { // older versions of IE
                            viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body' )[0].clientWidth,
                            viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body' )[0].clientHeight
                        }
                        document.write('<a onclick="return false;" href="<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' 
                            . FB_WM_BASEDIR; ?>/index.php?KeepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=' 
                            + viewportheight + '&amp;width=' + viewportwidth 
                            + '&amp;modal=false" class="thickbox button"><?php _e( 'Preview', FB_WM_TEXTDOMAIN ); ?></a>' );
                        //-->
                    </script>
```

Also it is important, that you initialize all requirements, via `add_thickbox();`. Inside the Thickbox you can load your parent data.

Comment: I used the following function to invoke light box on copy button:function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'post.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url('/lightbox-form.js', __FILE__) );
    
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );